# Is it Possible To Take Full And Differential Backup in Postgresql Like Sql Server?

Tags: postgresql, backup, postgresql-9.6, postgresql-12

I have a postgresql server. I want to take its backup full and differential mode as it is like in sql server. Is it possible to do this in postgresql? How can i do it, if it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing built-in for Postgres.

But two very popular backup tools support differential backups:

- [barman](https://www.pgbarman.org/)
- [pgbackrest](https://pgbackrest.org/)

Answer (score 4):

There is method called [continuous Wal_Archiving](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/continuous-archiving.html),  that can simulate The Diff backups in MSSQL

You run  [pg_basebackup](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgbasebackup.html) instead of pg_dump, then ship the WAL_Logs to the backups server.

To recover from a failure,  restore the last good backup and replay the WALs from the point in time from the last backup.

Depending on configuration can be better than DIFF backups as this gets the sever up to the last WAL file.

[Here is a nice write up](https://support.qasymphony.com/hc/en-us/articles/360006834212-Continuous-WAL-Archiving-for-Windows)